# PHP & Analytics API - Get 10 rows

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using [Google Analytics Core Reporting V4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/)

With the following code I'm setting up a request for google analytics.

```
// Create the ReportRequest object.
$request = new Google_Service_AnalyticsReporting_ReportRequest();
$request->setViewId($this->sViewId);
$request->setDateRanges($dateRange);
$request->setMetrics(array($pageViews));
$request->setDimensions(array($city));
$request->setOrderBys($order);
```

How can I tell the request to only get the 10 highest cities and ignore the rest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the documentation it seems that the [Report Request has a pageSize property](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet#reportrequest):

> Page size is for paging and specifies the maximum number of returned
>   rows. Page size should be >= 0. A query returns the default of 1,000
>   rows. The Analytics Core Reporting API returns a maximum of 10,000
>   rows per request, no matter how many you ask for. It can also return
>   fewer rows than requested, if there aren't as many dimension segments
>   as you expect. For instance, there are fewer than 300 possible values
>   for ga:country, so when segmenting only by country, you can't get more
>   than 300 rows, even if you set pageSize to a higher value.

So this should work via setPageSize:

```
$request->setPageSize(10);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a weird move from Google, the REST API query is `max-results=n`